# Cannot type my password in CMD for Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to upload my php application to Appengine using CMD. When I ran appcfg.py update myappname/, it asked me to fill in my gmail account but I cannot type in password !! I tried copying and paste but it doesn't work at all. Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: The password is hidden, but typing it should still work, once you've pressed enter.  Is this not the case?

Comment: It's not hidden, I tried typing my password and pressed enter, No response !!